# How to capture the "JavaScript SetCookie event" in a WebBrowser?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, cookiecontainer

How to capture the "JavaScript  SetCookie event"  in a WebBrowser? I want to synchronize the cookie to a CookieContainer when a javascript setcookie event occurred simultaneously. 
such as

```
<script>document.cookie="testcookie"</script>
```

Is there an event related to this ? thanks.

Environment: .Net 2.0 WebBrowser, C#, VS2008

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/5RsTm/4/

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no event that is raised when `document.cookie` is assigned.