# How to block all client cookies with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there a way to block all cookies sent to client from a webpage using javascript? Is should not allow third-party cookies from iframes or other scripts as well.

I've thought about it, like a listener that triggers a set cookie event and block it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? The cookies are sent when the page is requested, i.e. *before* the JS is executed. Also, if someone requests your site, why would you want to prevent setting cookies from your site?

Comment: So, you want the server to send the client some code, that the client will run, to prevent the server sending the client more cookies?

Comment: My **first hit** with google gave me a duplicated... [How to capture the “JavaScript SetCookie event” in a WebBrowser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3664613/601179) . And the answer is **NO, it can't be done**

Comment: @gdoron — It isn't a duplicate. This question is about blocking cookies. The event listener is just a suggested approach.

Comment: @quentin indeed, the event listener is a suggested approach. It seems is not possible... My goal is to block all cookies that are added by a browser request, from any source (javascript, iframes, server).

I can easily delete the ones form the server, but I cannot read nor write the ones that are added by javascript code (ex: Google Analytics) or iframes (facebook like iframes).

Comment: Block other third party scripts, that's setting cookies using [GDPR solution like this](https://app.cookieyes.com)

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible.

You could fake it for the current domain by polling the cookies and deleting them as you spot them (this wouldn't work for cookies marked as http only) but you can't touch cookies from other origins using JavaScript.